# dynamic allocation of rows of 2D array in c++

Tags: c++, dynamic, rows, multidimensional-array

In c++, I can create a 2D array with fixed number of columns, say 5, as follows:

```
char (*c)[5];
```

then I can allocate memory for rows as follows

```
c = new char[n][5];
```

where n can be any variable which can be assigned value even at run time. I would like to know whether and how can I dynamically allocate variable amount of memory to each row with this method. i.e. I want to use first statement as such but can modify the second statement.

Comment: Welcome to C++! Please throw away your C-style knowledge and indulge in `std::vector` and `std::array`! If you prefer, `boost::multi_array` is also an option!

Comment: You said C++, but you usually do stuff like this in C and not C++. Here is a nice link explaining how to [make dynamic arrays using malloc](http://c-faq.com/aryptr/dynmuldimary.html).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of a pointer to an array, you'd make a pointer to a pointer, to be filled with an array of pointers, each element of which is in turn to be filled with an array of chars:

```
char ** c = new char*[n];  // array of pointers, c points to first element

for (unsigned int i = 0; i != n; ++i)
    c[i] = new char[get_size_of_array(i)]; // array of chars, c[i] points to 1st element
```

A somewhat more C++ data structure would be a `std::vector<std::string>`.

As you noticed in the comment, dynamic arrays allocated with `new[]` cannot be resized, since there is no analogue of `realloc` in C++ (it doesn't make sense with the object model, if you think about it). Therefore, you should always prefer a proper container over any manual attempt at dynamic lifetime management.

In summary: Don't use `new`. Ever. Use appropriate dynamic containers.

Comment: I want to know whether I can fix the number of columns as in char (*c)[5] and then dynamically allocate the number of rows and not the other way round.

Comment: @sidharthsharma: Yes, use `std::vector<std::array<char, 5>>`. Dynamic arrays allocated with `new[]` cannot be resized; there is no `realloc`-analogue in C++.

Comment: Kerrek, this is one of the things that puzzle me about stackexchange: how do you explain the fact that I answered slightly more than a minute earlier than you, and yet you get all the upvotes while I get nothing?

Comment: @MikeNakis: You have at least 50% of the upvotes I have, that's not nothing!

Comment: LOL! you just upvoted me!  C-:=  Here, take one, too. Now I only have 33%. Explain _that_ now!

Comment: @Mike: `if(post.user.rep.is_high() && post.has_upvotes()) post.upvote();`.

Comment: @Xeo that is what I am suspecting, but I am looking for confirmation. I think I have also noticed it before with equivalent answers between me and Erik Lippert. He got 9, I got zilch.

Answer (score 1):

You need to declare c as follows: `char** c`; then, allocate the major array as follows: `c = new char*[n]`; and then, allocate each minor array as follows: `c[i] = new char[m]`

Comment: but that allocates a fixed number of rows n and not fixed number of columns. I just want to know whether something of that sort can be done or not.

Comment: It all depends on what you think of as a row and what you think of as a column. A two-dimensional array has two dimensions. One of them is the major, and the other is the minor. I have shown you how you can have a varying major, and a varying minor. It cannot get any more flexible than that. If you still have a problem with it, then you need to switch your understanding of what are columns and what are rows.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

main()
{
    int row,col,i,j;
    cout<<"Enter row and col\n";
    cin>>row>>col;

    int *a,(*p)[col]=new (int[row][col]);
    for(i=0;i<row;i++)
            for(j=0;j<col;j++)
                p[i][j]=i+j;

        for(i=0;i<row;i++)
            for(j=0;j<col;j++)
                cout<<i<<" "<<j<<" "<<p[i][j]<<endl;
                //printf("%d %d %d\n",i,j,p[i][j]);




}
```