# Stack Overflow exception thrown in method call

Tags: c++, exception, stack-overflow

I'm working on a problem in C++, but I'm getting a stack overflow exception and I can't tell why. The main method calls problem28(), but the first line should print "check" to my output, which isn't happening. If I define gridsize as 501 or less it runs fine, but anything more than that and it throws a stack overflow exception.

Any help would be appreciated.

```
#define right 0
#define down 1
#define left 2
#define up 3
#define gridsize 1001

int* next(int row, int col, int dir) {
    int* newPos = new int[2];
    newPos[0] = row;
    newPos[1] = col;
    switch(dir) {
    case right:
        newPos[1] += 1;
        break;
    case down:
        newPos[0] += 1;
        break;
    case left:
        newPos[1] -= 1;
        break;
    case up:
        newPos[0] -= 1;
        break;
    }
    return newPos;
}

int problem28() {
    cout << "check" << endl;
    int grid[gridsize][gridsize];
    for (int i = 0; i < gridsize; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < gridsize; j++)
            grid[i][j] = 0;
    int* pos = new int[2];
    pos[0] = pos[1] = gridsize / 2;
    int dir = right;


    for (int i = 1; i <= 1001; i++) {
        grid[pos[0]][pos[1]] = i;
        pos = next(pos[0], pos[1], dir);
        int* npos;

        npos = next(pos[0], pos[1], (dir + 1) % 4);
        if (grid[npos[0]][npos[1]] == 0)
            dir = (dir + 1) % 4;
    }
    cout << "generated grid" << endl;

    int total = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < gridsize; i++) {
        total += grid[i][i];
        total += grid[i][gridsize - i - 1];
    }
    total -= grid[gridsize / 2][gridsize / 2];

    return 0;
}

int main() {
    problem28();

    system("pause");
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: #pragma comment(linker, "/STACK:16777216") this gives you 16 mb of stack

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your stack is typically quite limited compared to memory overall. Since `problem28` doesn't seem to be recursive, by far the easiest fix that's most likely to work is to change:

```
int grid[gridsize][gridsize];
```

to:

```
static int grid[gridsize][gridsize];
```

That will allocate the memory for that array statically instead of locally, which will typically mean it's no longer on the stack.

Another possibility would be to use a `std::vector` instead of an array. This will will normally allocate its memory from the free store instead of locally. The minor problem is that `vector` (by itself) doesn't provide 2D addressing, so you'd have to handle that separately (e.g., using the [array_2D](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13655942/179910) I posted in a previous answer).

Comment: adding `static` did it. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

> If I define gridsize as 501 or less it runs fine, but anything more than that and it throws a stack overflow exception.

The entire `grid` array lives on the stack. If `int` is 32 bits wide, `int[500][500]` takes ~1MB, which happens to be the default maximum stack size on some operating systems.

You can either increase the size of the stack, or (preferably) allocate `grid` on the heap.

Comment: @phonetagger: not for the traditional values of `500` and `4`, and the traditional size of a megabyte.

Comment: @phonetagger: That makes your `int` 4x4 bytes wide. That's the first 2D `int` I've come across. :)

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be here:

```
int grid[gridsize][gridsize];
```

Did you try allocating this 2D array dynamically?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by allocating dynamically, so could you explain?

Comment: @user1898872 Either create the grid as static class member or use `new()` to prevent attaching the stack. 'Dynamically' usually means the latter, create a class instance on the heap.

Comment: Declaring grid as static did work, but doing `int* grid = new int[gridsize][gridsize];` doesn't compile. How would I dynamically allocate a 2D array?

Comment: That doesn't work directly, you first have do allocate an array of int pointers and fill in these with a dynamically allocated int. See here for a sample: [dynamic allocation of rows of 2D array in c++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8795969/dynamic-allocation-of-rows-of-2d-array-in-c).

Comment: BTW I would preferably use `std::vector` or `std::array`, thus you don't have to worry about the memory management.

Comment: Thanks, I'll probably just use one of those from now on since they're much more convenient.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend that you use a program such as Application Verifier to find the issue that is causing the crash:

[Application Verifier Download](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=20028)

It's important that you learn how to debug your software and understand what is going on. Please run your code in a debugger (Visual Studio, Eclipse) and take a look at where it stops. If you used Application Verifier, then it will likely stop where the issue originates. Take a look at the variables and see whether they make sense. Look at whether you're accessing memory locations you shouldn't.

To use Application Verifier with Visual Studio, install it then find the appVerifier.exe in the System32 folder in C:\Windows. Then open the file and point it to your executable. Enable what you think are the proper checks. Then run it in visual Studio.

For Linux you can (and should) use valgrind to detect these kind of issues